# INSERT INTO on duplicate key update of SQL query table

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, sql-update

My query work perfectly on all but one. I must empty the table in order to update the row.
I have a similar query that works perfectly and updates but I don't know how to make the same work with the query for vol table.

Query WORK and update:

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO compagnie (date, nbsvols, tempsvols, totaldistance, totalpassagers, totalcargo, totalfuel, consomoy, rbillets, rcargo, rcollations, totalrecettes, dfuel, dsalaires, dassurances, dtaxes, dpenalites, dmaintenance, dfraisfixes, totaldepenses, budjetinitial, budjetapflotte, benefice, budjet) 
VALUES ('$dated','$NrfFlights','$TFT','$TD','$TPC','$TCKG','$Totalfueluse','$Averagefuelconspermn','$TotalTicketsincome','$TotalCargoincome','$Totalcollationtincome','$Totalincome','$Totalfuelcost','$Totalsalary','$Totalinsurancecost','$Totalairporttaxecost','$PenalityPointscost','$Maintenancecost','$Fraisfixescecost','$Totaldepenses','$Initialbudjet','$bugjetapflotte','$Benef','$bugjetact') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nbsvols=$NrfFlights, tempsvols=$TFT, totaldistance=$TD, totalpassagers=$TPC, totalcargo=$TCKG, totalfuel=$Totalfueluse, consomoy=$Averagefuelconspermn, rbillets=$TotalTicketsincome, rcargo=$TotalCargoincome, rcollations=$Totalcollationtincome, totalrecettes=$Totalincome, dfuel=$Totalfuelcost, dsalaires=$Totalsalary, dassurances=$Totalinsurancecost, dtaxes=$Totalairporttaxecost, dpenalites=$PenalityPointscost, dmaintenance=$Maintenancecost, dfraisfixes=$Fraisfixescecost, totaldepenses=$Totaldepenses, budjetinitial=$Initialbudjet, budjetapflotte=$bugjetapflotte, benefice=$Benef, budjet=$bugjetact");
```

Query WORK but not update (my problem)

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO vol (id, UserName, CompanyName, PilotName, FlightId, FlightDate, rbilletsv, rcargov, rcollationsv, totalrecettesv, dfuelv, dsalairesv, dcrewcostv, dassurancesv, dtaxesv, dpenalitesv, dmaintenancev, totaldepensesv, beneficev)
    SELECT id, 
    UserName, 
    CompanyName, 
    PilotName, 
    FlightId, 
    FlightDate, 
    NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket AS rbilletsv,
    CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo AS rcargov, 
    NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation AS rcollationsv, 
    NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation AS totalrecettesv,
    StartFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel - EndFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel AS dfuelv,
    time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarypilotperh / 3600 AS dsalairesv,
    time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarycrewperh / 3600 AS dcrewcostv,
    NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentinsurance + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentinsurance + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentinsurance AS dassurancesv,
    NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentairporttaxe + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentairporttaxe + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentairporttaxe AS taxesv, 
    PenalityPoints * $PrixPenalityPointscost AS dpenalitesv,
    time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixmaintenancej / 3600,
    StartFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel - EndFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel + time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarypilotperh / 3600 + time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarycrewperh / 3600 + NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentinsurance + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentinsurance + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentinsurance + NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentairporttaxe + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentairporttaxe + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentairporttaxe + PenalityPoints * $PrixPenalityPointscost + time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixmaintenancej / 3600 AS totaldepensesv,
    NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket + CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo + NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation - StartFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel + EndFuelQuantity * $Prixkgfuel - time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarypilotperh / 3600 - time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixsalarycrewperh / 3600 - NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentinsurance - CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentinsurance - NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentinsurance - NbrPassengers * $PrixTicket * $Percentairporttaxe - CargoWeight * $Prixkgcargo * $Percentairporttaxe - NbrPassengers * $Prixcollation * $Percentairporttaxe - PenalityPoints * $PrixPenalityPointscost - time_to_sec(TotalBlockTime) * $Prixmaintenancej / 3600 AS beneficev
    FROM flights");
```

Comment: Why not use `update` if you want to update the row?  Second, what are the primary/unique keys on the table?

Comment: I cant use UPDATE because each day some row are added in "flights" table. And the "vol" are growing. The primary/unique keys of table vol is "id".

Comment: The second query doesn't have `on duplicate key update`, so it should just return an error if an id already exists.

Comment: the second query have no "on duplicate key update" because i dont know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `on duplicate key update` for your second query as:

```
on duplicate key update UserName = values(UserName),
                        CompanyName = values(CompanyName),
                        . . .
```

You need to do this for each column.  However, you don't have to repeat the formulas.  You can use `values()` with the name of the column in the column list.

Comment: Thank you, i test it this first solution this night and I post answer tommorow.